# Функции в javascript

Tags: javascript, функции

```
function one(idelementa,r,g,b,a) {  
    document.getElementById("idelementa").style.background ='"rgba('+r+','+g+','+b+',' +a+')" ';
}      
function too(idelementa) {  
    document.getElementById("idelementa").style.background = "rgba(100,100,100, 0.0)";
}
```

Беда в   `='"rgba('+r+','+g+','+b+',' +a+')" ';` ,тут, наверное, кавычки кусаются.

Comment: document.getElementById('ololololo').style.background = "rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + "," + a + ")"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function one(idelementa, r, g, b, a)
{
    document.getElementById(idelementa).style.background =
        "rgba(" + [r,g,b,a].join(",") + ")";
}

function too(idelementa)
{
    document.getElementById(idelementa).style.background =
        "rgba(100,100,100, 0.0)";
}
```

Comment: Вместо     document.getElementById("idelementa").style.background  написал:
    id:idelementa.style.background ="rgba(" + [r,g,b,a].join(",") + ")"; и работает) ,а с getElementById не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, аргумент idelementa в getElementById должен быть без кавычек. Во-вторых, да, кавычки в самом выражении неправильно стоят, там всё проще:

```
function one (idelementa,r,g,b,a)
{
    document.getElementById(idelementa).style.background ='rgba('+r+','+g+','+b+','+a+')'; 
}
```

Comment: так тоже работает,но вместо document.getElementById("idelementa").style.background написал: id:idelementa.style.background ="rgba(" + [r,g,b,a].join(",") + ")"; а с getElementById не работает.